# Определить победителя

Tags: логика, php

Итак, если игра на node.js после окончания игры нода делает запрос к php сценарию, который должен определить победителя и сделать соответствующие записи в базе.

**Наш массив:**

```
[users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => de2983f989ccf1ea09d1e29a0465fb51
                    [earn] => 32
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => ef21eb9ea4b5dc9f359024198bf40742
                    [earn] => 23
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => fff294012895b487157efd570232f0fc
                    [earn] => 22
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => 3bf51dd7bb302ccf81e335879b97bc5b
                    [earn] => 12
                )

        )
```

**[hash]** - идентификатор пользователя

**[earn]**  - достижения в игре, например игровые очки

Задача определить победителей, начислить рейтинг, записать логи в базу (плюсануть счетчик сыгранных игр, сделать запись о победной или проигранной игре и тп. )

**Теперь мне нужно этот массив проверить следующим образом:**
     - если все 4 пользователя набрали одинаковое кол-во очков: выдать все по 25% рейтинга

**если если флаг к примеру $a = true**

- первые 2 места получают рейтинг (1 место 70%, второе место 30%)
- если на первом и втором месте ничья, распределить рейтинг 50 на 50
- если 2 и 3 место набрали одинаковое кол-во очков, распределить 30% рейтинга по 15 каждому
- если 2 и 3 и 4 место набрали одинаковое кол-во очков, распределить 30% рейтинга по 10 каждому

**если если флаг к примеру $a = false**

- рейтинг получает первое место
- если 1 и 2 место ничья, рейтинг делим 50 на 50
- если 1 и 2 и 3 место ничья, рейтинг делим по 33%

Собственно начал делать это дело и попал в бездну конструкций if else, копал в сторону паттерна стратегии, но как оказалось он не подходит в данной ситуации, подскажите пожалуйста как оптимально реализовать это все дело?

Comment: > попал в бездну конструкций if else, копал в сторону паттерна стратегии
Можно написать кучей ифов (самый оптимальный по затратам-выхлопу вариант), можно написать большой процессор, который будет принимать участников и свод правил, но я бы начал с определения того, зачем вам нужен node.js, если вы им не пользуетесь.

Comment: Тут условия примитивные...  

    if ( sizeof( array_unique( array_map( function($x){return $x["earn"];}, $users ) ) ) == 1 ) {
        strategy1( $users ); // если у всех одинаково
    } elseif ( $a ) {
        strategy2( $users ); // если тру
    } else {
        strategy3( $users ); // если не тру
    }
Выделить разные стратегии распределения очков более чем логично, поэтому __бездны конструкций if else__ не будет.

Comment: Попробуйте так:

1. отсортируйте и сгруппируйте по результату
2. в соответствии с параметрами (и возможно размерами групп) выделите каждой группе по доле прибавки рейтинга (здесь вполне подойдёт «Стратегия», кстати)
3. разделите рейтинг в группах поровну

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, очень странно видеть ваши рассуждения про равенство очков игроков, притом что вы в примере показали для всех разное количество, и не указали как у вас будет распределяться рейтинг в этой ситуации. вполне возможно ваши распределения рейтинга попадают под какую-то табличную функцию или рейтинг рассчитывается пропорцией. а то, как вы описали задачу, да будет куча ифов....